# Automating the build process of our embedded c++ apps, which currently use VisualGDB

Tags: c++, cmake, build, msbuild

I have been tasked with creating a CICD pipeline for our embedded c++ apps which means I want to build our app completely from the command line. I’ll also be using AWS Codepipeline and Codebuild services and I’d prefer to run the build process on a Linux machine.

With that said, our c++ apps (.sln) can contain one or many projects. Further, our developers build all our c++ apps with VisualGDB using MSBuild with a custom tool chain which targets our Linux device (we don't build our app for other platforms).

To continue, I noticed that there are many VisualGDB-specific files like: *.vgdbsettings and *.msbuild-mak. I'm unsure what these files do or if they are needed but I feel confident that we only use VisualGDB to add a custom toolchain to our build process. If that's the case, can I skip using VisualGDB altogether and instead do something like this:

1. create a CMakeList.txt file using a package like `cmake-converter`
2. run `cmake` command while passing in our custom toolchain, like this `cmake /path/to/src -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/toolchain/foo-bar-baz.cmake`.
3. And, finally, run `make`.

Am I on the right track? Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.